# Stop log4net logging process and remove log file lock

Tags: c#, log4net

I am working on a windows service application that is supposed to run jobs scheduled at specific times. Each job execution cycle is logged using log4net and has its own file per execution(With 5 jobs running for 5 days once a day there will be 25 log files created).

The question is, how do I stop the log4net log file lock so that once the job has finished execution I can email the log file and delete it from the hard drive?

I need to do this programatically, so the config file setting would not work in this case.

I have tried this so far, but it doesn't work:

```
    logger.Logger.Repository.LevelMap.Clear();
    logger.Logger.Repository.LevelMap.Add(logger.Logger.Repository.LevelMap["OFF"]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using a FileAppender, you can set the LockingModel to MinimalLock:

```
Dim fileAppenderTrace As New log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender
fileAppenderTrace.ImmediateFlush = True
fileAppenderTrace.LockingModel = New FileAppender.MinimalLock()
fileAppenderTrace.ActivateOptions()
```

It'll release the file after each log entry is written, not after the job is done, so I'm not sure if that's entirely what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, that was what I was looking for. I will see now how the  C# version of the above code should look like. Thank you.